# Printer Management

Tags: drivers, printer, network-printer

On our network we are  getting an error every time we attempt to add a printer or sometimes print to printers. The error states that new drivers are needed to installed to print however we are using Xerox global driver. On my computer for example, I can print to the printer I have always been connected to, however I can not connect to any other printer. So far we found that when we remove windows update KB5005030 on the computer it will work again however now there are computers that do not have the update that are prompting for the driver update. If anyone has seen this issue before or can offer any advice it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just as a point of clarification, were the Xerox global drivers signed by Microsoft?  I know that the more recent versions of Windows (e.g. >= Win8, maybe as far back as Vista) look for drivers that have been digitally signed, and it has been known to cause problems if the driver in use is not signed.

Answer (score 3):

With newer update you need to set that registry key to 0 to allow user to install print driver.

The registry is: RestrictDriverInstallationToAdministrators

The location is: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Printers\PointAndPrint

You need to set it to 0 (DWORD)

With SCCM or other method you can push print driver, or keep it mind that registry key don’t need a reboot, so as it’s a security risk you can set it, push the printer and unset it after. (Or just leave it at zero if you are confident for the security risk it bring)

Comment: Thank you for the help, when I go to that path on regedit I hit printers and don't see PointAndPrint. In the printer section could I make a registry named RestrictDriverInstallationToAdministrators and set that to 0? Or should I look somewhere else?

Comment: @starman Hi, you need the key in the correct location, in the folder PointAndPrint. It’s normal you don’t see all key there, in the policy si folder it’s policy push to your computer. That just mean you don’t have PointAndPrint settings push

Comment: Is this a setting that I can change to enable users to update these drivers? Also, when I log in with an administrator account it allows the update driver bar to work and complete however it does not actually have an effect on the computer printing

Comment: @starman Yes, it allow them to update driver from your print server. Not from a package from the internet in example.

Comment: Thank you, how can we enable this without the PointAndPrint setting? Should I check on my print servers regedit?

Comment: I was able to add the registry key on our domain controllers group policies that mirrored what was listed and this was then applied to all of our computers. Printing appears to be working now and I will answer this question after a few days of monitoring.